# Samsung Galaxy Note 3 - Eye detection on non-native apps?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Although I feel that the eye detection still requires a lot of tweaks and performance improvements by Samsung, I would be more tempted to use it and test it if it worked with non-native apps.

For example, although Google Chrome comes pre-installed on the device, the eye detection will not work with it.

It would also be nice if the feature worked with messaging apps such as HandCent SMS.

To put it simply - Is there a way for this feature to work with apps you install on the device?

Comment: It works with actually 'native' apps: Samsung Intenet, Samsung SMS, Samsung Gallery etc. It is built into the Samsung Touchwiz itself so cannot be used 3rd party apps at present. Air gestures can, see Flipboard. This is for the smart scroll etc, the 'keep screen on' works over apps, so the screen shoulnd't lock while gaming etc. I havn't found any Xposed or other modules to override this. Just to clarify I mean native to Samsung Touchwiz, not native to Android itself. There's a subtle but very important distinction there.

Comment: That clears things up a lot as I assumed it was apps that was native to android or Samsung, not Touchwiz. I guess that answers my question.

Comment: yeah it's annoying. The way I look at it is: There's Android, then there's Samsung's version, HTCs version etc, and they are all different versions of the OS, but in a way are almost their own little OS. It drives me mad!

Comment: @RossC looks like you should sum that up to an answer, as Petay already wrote: *I guess that answers my question.* Give him a chance to upvote/accept :)

Comment: @Izzy done, and I added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an important distinction to be made: Android in its stock form, and Samsung's version of Android, with the Touchwiz framework.

The Touchwiz functionality for the eyeball recognition works with only with apps 'native' to Samsungs Touchwiz version of Android. Apps like Samsung SMS, Samsung Internet, Samsung Gallery etc.

Air Gestures can be ported to 3rd party apps, Flipboard is an example of this.

Fore the eye recognitions stuff, like  smart scroll etc. the app needs to be embedded in Touchwiz. However, the 'keep screen on' functionality works over apps, so the screen shouldn't lock while gaming etc.

After looking into this myself, I havn't found any [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) or other modules to override this for root users. Also, on the S4 Google Edition (running almost<sup>1</sup> stock Android) there is no eyeball recognition whatsoever, and cannot be implemented.

Also, from a developer's point of view it, even if it was possible to access this functionality, would it be worth implementing it for only one device, and not being accessible on any other phone? It's a good idea in a way, but I don't see it expanding for a while, until other OEMs decide on similar tech perhaps.

---

<sup>1</sup> Techincally the Touchwiz framework is there to enable the S-View cover. On the HTC One Google Edition HTC Sense is there to allow Beats Audio to be built in.